# File operation dialogs always appear on top of each other

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I just wondered if anyone knew of program that could cascade file operation dialogs (e.g. the dialog that appears when copying files) so that they don't appear in the middle of the screen always on top of one another.

If I copy 2 large files from an external hard drive to my desktop the file operation dialog appears for both but always on top of the other. If I begin copying a third file yet another dialog appears on top of the others. Can a program like Classic Shell be run to cascade the dialogs so I can see what operation is being performed without having to move them around my desktop into view. Classic Shell is capable of automatically expanding the 'more details' section of a file operation dialog so I hope it's possible to do the same with the position of these dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 and now Windows 10 stack the file move/copy dialogs so my issue is no longer present if I upgrade my OS.

[image: copy]

Answer (score 0):

There are other issues too with starting multiple copying in windows. If it is going to the same partition you will be causing fragmentations. Parts of each copy complete filling clusters, at the same time another file is in there filling another cluster, making a interleaved and fragmented mess from the disks perspective.

Some people would concider fragmentation on a NTFS system a non issue, but I would also add that besides sequential data movement being much faster, and OCD organisation and reduced time for defragging, it is a Recovery problem.  If you ever had to recover the data when the files tables are damaged or destroyed, the chances of recovery are much higher when the data is all contigious across the clusters.

What all this is trying to say, is mostly you just dont want to be doing this, if you can avoid it. CTRL select or SHIFT select whenever possible, and do it as one operation.

I wouldnt go on with all this blather, unless I could also suggest ways that you can do what your doing, and keep it in order, and keep fragmentation down, keep the dialogs where you can see them, and solution most of all the problems.

Terracopy and FastCopy two 3rd party file utilities, can be set to Wait till the one operation is finished before starting the next.  So you can quoe up many operations, it would then be handled one after the other, via the same dialog or same dialog location.
Both of these programs have many options, and can integrate into the OS at a replacement level all the way to being completely seperate.
At least one of them,  also follows normal windows conventions and allow the windows to be moved, and the location and size of the window to be stored, so it comes up in the same place you put it.

Before altering how the OS works and all, you might give those programs a try and see if they dont solve the problems you have along with the problem you dont see.  It can take time to get all the options set and get things to work exactally the way you desire, but it could be worth it.

Ramifications:
 With any quoed actions, if you did something twice, or made changes after , neither of the programs are all seeing and all knowing, so you can get a stopping or error because the quoe has something done stupidly in it. been there done that.

Move operations, within the same partition. Move operations via the OS method are to just change the File tables ONLY to set the new location for the file. With fastcopy there have been times when it instead moves all the data, an unnessisary operation.  I prefer to integrate them into the OS, but not Replace the os, because of that.

Comment: Does the same apply to SD cards in terms of fragmentation?
Thanks, I will check out Terracopy and FastCopy.

Comment: SD cards get Fragmentation, they are block accessed data with a cluster configurations still. It does not effect thier read speeds as much at all. It is likly again that any needed recovery would go much better with contiguous data.